# Flutter - Native Android Component invoke with MethodChannel only works on first time then throws MissingPluginException

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app with a native android component for scanning barcodes, on first run this native component runs fine and does what it needs to then returns to the Flutter section of app.

However, anytime after that if you try to open the native android component again it always throws the error: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method StartSecondActivity on channel com.example)

Only restarting the app seems to solve this problem, where it will run once with no error then repeat.

dart looks something like this, runs first time and gets error any subsequent tries unless app is restarted:

```
    MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('com.example');
    await _channel.invokeMethod('StartSecondActivity');
```

MainActivity.java class:

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
    import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
    import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache;
    import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
    import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

    public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.example";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        flutterEngine.getNavigationChannel().setInitialRoute("/waybill");

        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put("bac_flutter_id", flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                if(call.method.equals("StartSecondActivity")){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentWedgeSample.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //result.success("ActivityStarted");
                }else{
                    //result.notImplemented();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Fairly new to Flutter and did not originally write this app so any hints on how to go about solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: After the first call, Flutter is awaiting for a result from the MethodChannel call. You can't call another one if still waiting. So I think you just need to uncomment those 2 lines with result.success or result.notImplemented

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for response, tried this but still same error. I can get the result first time ("ActivityStarted") but second time it still throws error and never resolves

Comment: so the bad behavior could be due to the IntentWedgeSample intent. Maybe is still running or not stopped correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by using Android Intent+ plugin instead of MethodChannel (https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus)

Then instead of the MethodChannel code, use:

```
           AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
            action: 'android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW',

            // Replace this by your package name.
            package: 'com.example',

            // Replace this by your package name followed by the activity you want to open.
            // The default activity provided by Flutter is MainActivity, but you can check
            // this in AndroidManifest.xml.
            componentName: 'com.example.IntentWedgeSample',
          );

          await intent.launch();
```